# Can I build UCS Death Star by buying bricks separately?

Tags: sets, shopping

I'd like to get the UCS Death Star, but it's too expensive :(

I got the build manual, and I see what bricks I need. I am thinking of buying them separately via Bricklink.

Has anyone tried doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a whole site dedicated to working out how you can build a particular model using parts from other sets - [Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/sets/10143-1). A combination of that and Bricklink would be cheaper as you'd end up with fewer extra parts.

There's also a [thread on EuroBricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=76046) where someone has done what you're doing and there are some useful tips (mostly about buying as much as you can from a small number of sellers to avoid huge postage costs). [Brickset's "links" tab](http://brickset.com/sets/10143-1) is handy for more information on the set.